# Get local paths for all cached resource files

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Using Firefox addon SDK, is there a way to get the local paths for all the resources (css, js, images) of the page that is currently opened in a tab?

I'm trying to implement the functionality of saving pages locally (kind of like "File" -> "Save page as..."), and for that I need to know the location of the resources that were downloaded by the browser along with the HTML page itself;

Answer (score 0):

**Visit this link**

To enable the application cache for an application, you must include the manifest attribute in the  element in your application's pages, as go in the following 
link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache